# How to change tooltip display position

Tags: c#, tooltip

I implemented the `Tooltip.Show(String, IWin32Window, Point, Int32)` in `OnMouseMove`, such that I could specify the position where tooltip is shown, the only problem I have with this method is that tooltip  displays as the mouse is moving.

I tried to use `Tooltip.SetToolTip` for which I could specify `AutomaticDelay`, so that the tooltip will be displayed when mouse is stopped for seconds. But in this method tooltip will be positioned in the center of the associated control.

So I registered `ToolTip.Draw` event, but I didn't find where to change the Tooltip display position.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you would like to remove tooltip whenever user continues moving mouse over your controls. I guess you can continue using **Tooltip.Show(String, IWin32Window, Point, Int32)** in "OnMouseMove", just call **ToolTip.Hide(IWin32Window win)** whenever you detect the mouse movement when the tooltip is already shown.